# Adding input fields in XSLT for specified XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm totally new to XSLT and I've encoutered a problem with input fields. I need to be able to update given xml file with input fields as show in this code fragment(basically being able to add more senators to given base). Only tutorial i found shows input fields in form where you got id and value, which is different from my file(it can't be change due to excercise conditions) and I was unable to edit tutorial code to match with my XML file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- source: http://www.senate.gov/general/contact_information/senators_cfm.xml -->
<contact_information>
    <member>
        <member_full>Alexander (R-TN)</member_full>
        <last_name>Alexander</last_name>
        <first_name>Lamar</first_name>
        <party>R</party>
        <state>TN</state>
        <address>
            455 DIRKSEN SENATE OFFICE BUILDING WASHINGTON DC 20510
        </address>
        <phone>(202) 224-4944</phone>
        <email> http://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/index.cfm?p=Email </email>
        <website>http://www.alexander.senate.gov/</website>
        <class>Class II</class>
        <bioguide_id>A000360</bioguide_id>
    </member>
    <member>
        <member_full>Ayotte (R-NH)</member_full>
        <last_name>Ayotte</last_name>
        <first_name>Kelly</first_name>
        <party>R</party>
        <state>NH</state>
        <address>
             144 RUSSELL SENATE OFFICE BUILDING WASHINGTON DC 20510
        </address>
        <phone>(202) 224-3324</phone>
        <email>http://www.ayotte.senate.gov/?p=contact</email>
        <website>http://www.ayotte.senate.gov</website>
        <class>Class III</class>
        <bioguide_id>A000368</bioguide_id>
    </member>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by an "input field" as neither XML or XSLT has the concept of input fields. Thanks!

Comment: A HTML form for entering senator data. All information fields from the source XML file (use data-senators.xml) should be represented as input fields in the form.

this is the task i got, senators xml just contains some imaginary info about people like name, adress etc. Guess i should be able to add more people through that form